# How to check output from the serial port match a message to continue write a command in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I use this code to initialize a serial port in C# :

```
serialPort.PortName = cboCOMPort.Text;
serialPort.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cboBaudRate.Text);
serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
serialPort.DataBits = 8;
serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialDataReceived);
serialPort.Open();
```

then use this code to read data from serial port :

```
private void SerialDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
      SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
      strDataReceived = serialPort.ReadExisting();                
      ShowSerialOutput(strDataReceived);         
}
```

and write :

```
private void SerialDataSend(string strCommand)
{
      serialPort.WriteLine(strCommand);   
}
```

**My problem** : when a device (example a switch) connects to the serial port and executes a command I have written, my program has to wait for the switch finishes executing this command before writing a new command to the serial port. How to check if the switch is finished? (when finished, the switch will send some message contain the keywords like 'completed', 'finished',...). I have tried to use this code but not work :

```
while(true)
    {
         if(serialPort.ReadLine().Contains("completed"))
              serialDataSend(nextCommand);
    }
```

Sorry for not clearly explaining my problem.
**Example my problem : **
I connect to the switch using serial port and use my program to read/write data. I want to copy a large file from server to the switch using this command : cp tftp://10.0.0.1/file.tgz /var/tmp/file.tgz. I use my program to write this command to the serial port and the switch executes this command. The file is very large so the program need to wait the file copied completely before sending the next command. When finished, the switch show message "Completed". That is my problem : how to check the copy process completed to write the new command.

Comment: let's clarify a little.. what exactly does not work? it sounds like a process flow issue, could you describe a little more in detail the process you intend to implement?

Comment: You'll have to make up your mind how you are going to read data from the serial port.  Right now that DataReceived event does not help you to do it correctly, remove it.

Comment: If you use "ReadLine()", that means you are waiting for a something with "\n" at the end. You can also use "Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)", it means if SerialPort data to be read is available, then you get the data, without waiting for "\n" in the data.

Comment: I've just edited my question. Hope that's more clearly. Please review my question and give me some helps. Thank in advanced :)

Comment: does your problem still persist? is the message with an upper or lower case `C` ?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to approach your problem. Probably will need to rephrase as more information might come from you :)

As I understand it you have more than 1 command that you are sending to the device. Something like a command-list.
As you already have the event for data reception you could also use it to verify whether the `completed` keyword has been send and set a flag.
EDIT: The flag you can use for the while-wait-loop as you already do.
Your program will wait there until your device confirms the completion and jump out of the loop. Then you need to reset the flag for the next waiting loop.

```
public class DeviceCommunication
{
    bool FlagToProceed = false;

    private void MainJob()
    {
        // send command 1...
        SerialDataSend("cp tftp://10.0.0.1/file.tgz /var/tmp/file.tgz.");

        // wait
        while(!FlagToProceed)
        {}
        // reset the flag
        FlagToProceed = false;

        // send command 2 ...
        SerialDataSend("WhatEverComesNext");    

        // wait
        while(!FlagToProceed)
        {}    
        // reset the flag
        FlagToProceed = false;

    }

    private void SerialDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
          SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
          strDataReceived = serialPort.ReadExisting();                
          ShowSerialOutput(strDataReceived); 

          // check whether affirmation has been received and open the gates
          if(strDataReceived.Contains("completed"))
          {   
              FlagToProceed = true;
          }                  
    }

    private void SerialDataSend(string strCommand)
    {
          serialPort.WriteLine(strCommand);   
    }    
}
```

This waiting technique is not a very good one! It is just the closest to your posted code. If you want to use it, I would suggest to have a timer running and break out of the `while` - loop if timeout is reached. Otherwise you might keep stuck in the while loop if the device decides **not** to confirm with "complete" or data just gets lost during transmission.

Another possibility to solve your problem could be to apply an [asynch / await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) approach.

EDIT: be ware of case sensitivity! "Complete" & "complete" is not the same for the `Contains` method!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a state machine and [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) to achieve what you are trying to do.  See the code below, I recommend doing all this in a separate thread other then Main.  You keep track of the state you're in, and when you get a response you parse it with the correct callback function and if it is what you are expecting you move onto the next send command state.

```
private delegate void CallbackFunction(String Response);    //our generic Delegate
private CallbackFunction CallbackResponse;                  //instantiate our delegate
private StateMachine currentState = ATRHBPCalStateMachine.Waiting;

SerialPort sp;  //our serial port

private enum StateMachine
{
    Waiting,
    SendCmd1,
    Cmd1Response,
    SendCmd2,
    Cmd2Response,
    Error
}

private void do_State_Machine()
{
    switch (StateMachine)
    {
        case StateMachine.Waiting:
            //do nothing
            break;
        case StateMachine.SendCmd1:
            CallbackResponse = Cmd1Response;    //set our delegate to the first response
            sp.Write("Send first command1");    //send our command through the serial port

            currentState = StateMachine.Cmd1Response;   //change to cmd1 response state
            break;
        case StateMachine.Cmd1Response:
            //waiting for a response....you can put a timeout here
            break;
        case StateMachine.SendCmd2:
            CallbackResponse = Cmd2Response;    //set our delegate to the second response
            sp.Write("Send command2");  //send our command through the serial port

            currentState = StateMachine.Cmd2Response;   //change to cmd1 response state
            break;
        case StateMachine.Cmd2Response:
            //waiting for a response....you can put a timeout here
            break;
        case StateMachine.Error:
            //error occurred do something
            break;
    }
}

private void Cmd1Response(string s)
{
    //Parse the string, make sure its what you expect
    //if it is, then set the next state to run the next command
    if(s.contains("expected"))
    {
        currentState = StateMachine.SendCmd2;
    }
    else
    {
        currentState = StateMachine.Error;
    }
}

private void Cmd2Response(string s)
{
    //Parse the string, make sure its what you expect
    //if it is, then set the next state to run the next command
    if(s.contains("expected"))
    {
        currentState = StateMachine.Waiting;
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        currentState = StateMachine.Error;
    }
}

//In my case, I build a string builder until I get a carriage return or a colon character.  This tells me
//I got all the characters I want for the response.  Now we call my delegate which calls the correct response
//function.  The datareceived event can fire mid response, so you need someway to know when you have the whole
//message.
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string CurrentLine = "";
    string Data = serialPortSensor.ReadExisting();

    Data.Replace("\n", "");

    foreach (char c in Data)
    {
        if (c == '\r' || c == ':')
        {
            sb.Append(c);

            CurrentLine = sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();

            CallbackResponse(CurrentLine);  //calls our correct response function depending on the current delegate assigned
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
```

I would put this in a background worker, and when you press a button or something you can set the current state to `SendCmd1`.

Button press

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        currentState = StateMachine.SendCmd1;

        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Background worker do work event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            break;

        do_State_Machine();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```